# Check value returning from preg_replace() exists or no in array

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

I have one message string 
e.g:

```
$data="Hey my dear :laugh: how are you :mmmmm: :smile: and non existing smile :go: ";
```

and I have smile array(for checking)

```
$smileys=array("laugh","mmmm","smile");
```

yesterday friends helped me and I convert `:smile:` type to [image] like down

```
$data=preg_replace("/:([a-zA-Z]+):/","<img src='images/smileys/$1.png' class='smile'>",$data);
```

and how can I check this smile exists or no in array?

example: http://masters.az
login:test
pass:test
code example:http://masters.az/message-3

Comment: Your question looks unrelated to the code you've shared. Can you please edit the question and post (at least) proper sample data we can use in our answers? (Whatever, it should trivial to loop and array and look for substring matches.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implode the terms with an `or` then use the found term in the replace.

```
$data = "Hey my dear :laugh: how are you :mmmmm: :smile: and non existing smile :go: ";
$smileys = array("laugh","mmmm","smile");
echo preg_replace('/:(' . implode('|', $smileys) . '):/', '<img src="images/smileys/$1.png" class="$1">', $data);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/511095

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hI1aX0/1

Here's a JS approach:

```
var test = ["laugh","mmmm","smile"];
var regex = new RegExp(':(' + test.join('|') + '):', 'g');
var string = "Hey my dear :laugh: how are you :mmmmm: :smile: and non existing smile :go: ";
var string = string.replace(regex, '<img src="images/smileys/$1.png" class="$1">');
console.log(string);
console.log(regex);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8fj00bg5/

Comment: Oh woow great code,thank you :) :) I need js form of these codes

Comment: Updated with JS approach. The `console.log` is just for demonstration (you'll need to open developer console to see it), that can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$data = "Hey my dear :laugh: how are you :mmmmm: :smile: and non existing smile :go: ";
$smileys = array("laugh","mmmm","smile");
$data = preg_replace_callback("/:([a-zA-Z]+):/",
    function ($m) use($smileys) {
        if (in_array($m[1], $smileys) )
            return "<img src='images/smileys/$m[1].png' class='smile'>";

    },
    $data);
echo $data,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Hey my dear <img src='images/smileys/laugh.png' class='smile'> how are you  <img src='images/smileys/smile.png' class='smile'> and non existing smile
```

Comment: It absolutely worked,I'm looking for whether it has problem or no.If it has I'll write.Thanks so much :)

Comment: @FuadPashayev: Sorry, I don't know very much javascript, but I thing there is some kind of callback routine that can be used in replace method like in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array() function. Explanation is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)

Then you should try this:-

```
    $data="Hey my dear :laugh: how are you :mmmmm: :smile: and non existing smile :go: ";
$smileys=array("laugh","mmmm","smile");
foreach ($smileys as $sm)
{
    $data1=preg_replace("/:([a-zA-Z]+):/",$sm,"<img src='images/smileys/$1.png' class='smile'>");
    if(stristr($data,$sm))
    {
       echo $sm." matched"."<br>";
    }
}
```

reference is [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_replace.htm)

Comment: I now that but I have to search value from preg_replace() in array.
Because i have no define strings.

Comment: $smileys=array("laugh","mmmm","smile");
foreach ($smileys as $sm)
{
    $data1=preg_replace("/:([a-zA-Z]+):/",$sm,"<img src='images/smileys/$1.png' class='smile'>");
    print($data1);echo "<br>";
}

but in this code there are no information of $data,where does it check?

Comment: It worked but if there are smile in string data that is not exist in array displaying like broke image(square).